# How to set {{collection}} child view CSS class names from content properties in ember.js 1.0-pre?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In ember.js 0.9.x the child view CSS class could be set this way:

```
{{#collection
    contentBinding="App.someController"
    itemClassBinding="content.someProperty"}}

    {{content.displayProperty}}

{{/collection}}
```

In ember.js 1.0-pre this doesn't seem to work anymore, what would be the equivalent code in this case?

Here is a [working example with ember.js 0.9.3](http://jsfiddle.net/Bamaz/), and here are [some failed atempts with ember.js 1.0-pre](http://jsfiddle.net/ckypx/).